# Html bootstrap link error

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot connect bootstrap's files from my index.html.as my code file belong ; my index.html file locates in /var/www/html as "localhost" . but when i start to localhost/bootstrap/index.html , i can access my website only without any CSS properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Bilsay Mavi
        </title>
        <link href=../css/bootstrap.min.css rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
<body>
<h1>DENEME</h1>
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bilsay</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried `<link href=localhost/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css rel="stylesheet">` and `<link href=/var/www/html/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css rel="stylesheet">`

but I can't access with CSS file .how can i solve this error?

Comment: Try `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: What Lal said. FYI for an absolute address, you want `http://localhost...`

Comment: Also you are missing `" "` for href as the value for attributes should be enclosed within `"`

Comment: how does your folder structure looks like?

Comment: i dont know structure looks like . how can i learn it?